# Proper use of yieldIfContendedSafely() in an Android Multithreaded Application

Tags: android, multithreading, android-sqlite

In my application, I am using an `AsyncTask` to write some data to a database in a transaction. This database is also accessed from the UI thread. While looking through the available database methods, I came across `yieldIfContendedSafely()`. It seems like this method should be used for any cases where a transaction is being made from a separate thread. But there is hardly any documentation on this method other than the following:

> Temporarily end the transaction to let other threads run. The transaction is assumed to be successful so far. Do not call `setTransactionSuccessful` before calling this. When this returns a new transaction will have been created but not marked as successful. This assumes that there are no nested transactions (`beginTransaction` has only been called once) and will throw an exception if that is not the case.

Here is how I would assume that you would use this method from a thread:

```
        try {
        db.beginTransaction();
        //insert some stuff into the database here 
        ...



        // is this how you use this method?
        boolean yielded = db.yieldIfContendedSafely();
        if (yielded) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }



        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        return false;
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
        db.close();
    }
```

Is this the correct way to use this method? Is it alright to use `db.yieldIfContendedSafely()` more than once in the same transaction, in between multiple writes to different tables in the database? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pulling some example code from the Android libraries it seems **much** simpler to use than that...

This is taken from com.android.providers.calendar.SQLiteContentProvider.java

```
@Override
public int bulkInsert(Uri uri, ContentValues[] values) {
    int numValues = values.length;
    mDb = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    mDb.beginTransactionWithListener(this);
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < numValues; i++) {
            Uri result = insertInTransaction(uri, values[i]);
            if (result != null) {
                mNotifyChange = true;
            }
            mDb.yieldIfContendedSafely();
        }
        mDb.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
        mDb.endTransaction();
    }

    onEndTransaction();
    return numValues;
}
```

Also looking into the source code for the function itself, it seems that, if yielded, the call will defer execution of your thread for a short period in any case.